# C++ type casting error setting and getting derived class members in/from an array (**)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, casting, type-conversion

Hi I'm having trouble with the set and get method in the Computer.cpp. I keep on getting type casting errors such as

> Invalid initialization of reference type 'const Case&' from expression
>   of type 'Case' or 'Part', 'Part*' etc.

What I want to do is to store different computer parts ("Part" is a superclass of various concrete parts such as case, monitor, cpu etc) into the array

```
Part** m_requiredParts;
```

Here are the code extract, I'm running it on qt creator 3.6.0.

Header file,

```
Computer.h 

#ifndef COMPUTER_H
#define COMPUTER_H

class Computer : public ComputerPlan
{
public:

    /**
     * @brief Computer default constructor
     */
    Computer();

    /**
     * @brief ~Computer destructor
     */
    virtual ~Computer();

    // Getters
    /**
     * @brief getCase retrieves the computer's case information
     * @return the computer's Case
     */
    virtual const Case& getCase() const;

    // Setters
    /**
     * @brief setCase setter method for Case
     * @param computerCase computer's Case
     */
    virtual void setCase(const Case &computerCase);

protected:

    Part** m_requiredParts;

};

#endif // COMPUTER_H
```

.CPP File

```
Computer.cpp

#include "Computer.h"

Computer::Computer()
{
    m_requiredParts = new Part* [8];
}

Computer::~Computer()
{

}

const Case& Computer::getCase() const
{
    const Case& c = (Case&)m_requiredParts[0];
    return c;
}

void Computer::setCase(const Case &computerCase)
{
    m_requiredParts[0] = (Part*) &computerCase;
    //Part**
}
```

to add some addtional info,

I'm setting and getting them in the following way in the main.cpp

```
Computer* computer = new Computer();
computer->setCase(Case("NZXT", Tower));
std::string expected = "Case: NZXT, Case Type: Tower";
std::string actual = std::string(computer->getCase().getPartInformation());
delete computer;
return expected == actual;
```

Comment: How do you call `setCase`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer per se but it is too big to be a comment and it needs to be pointed out

```
computer->setCase(Case("NZXT", Tower));
```

Creates a temporary `Case` that you capture with `const &` in `setCase`.  A `const &` extends the lifetime of the temporary into the the function so we are okay there.  Unfortunately you store a pointer to that temporary in `setCase`.  When the function ends the `const &` goes out of scope and the temporary now has nothing binding it so it is destroyed as well.  Now you have a pointer to an object that no longer exists.

You need to make sure the object that you pase to `setCase` is going to outlives the `Computer` you put it in.

Comment: Does this mean I need to deep-copy the object into the array to prevent this from happening?

Comment: @lukieleetronic Welll your class should have a proper copy constructor but that is not what I am getting at.  You need to make sure the `Case` object that you create an pass to `setCase` outlives the `Computer` object.  Otherwise you will have a pointer to an object that doesn't exist and trying to use it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Wow, Just to try it out, I've deep-copied the object and it works like a charm!, I didn't see the scope of the temporary being prematurely ending which was causing all this issues, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

You must dereference pointer from your pointers array:

```
const Case& c = (Case&)(*m_requiredParts[0]);
```

Also it is not good practice to use c-style type casts, use static_cast or dynamic_cast instead:

```
const Case& c = static_cast<Case&>(*m_requiredParts[0]);
```

<del>And it is bad idea possibly to store pointer to extarnal object inside your class instance.</del>

Regarding this `computer->setCase(Case("NZXT", Tower));` use case it is definitly bad idea to store pointer to temporary inside your class instance, use `new` and change prototype to accept pointer. And don't forget cleanup in destructor.

Comment: Thanks, I've forgot to deference my m_requiredParts!